# VS Code colourize problem with JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed with VS Code colourize problem with JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension. How do I fix the problem without removing the extension?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0fpE.png

Answer (score 1):

you need to add theme extension. it depends on what framework you are using. if you are using react search in extensions tab react theme and install it

Comment: I already have.

Comment: can you screenshot which extenstion you have installed ? go to the extensions tab and open current theme extension tab

Comment: Sir, I fixed the problem in a different way. I remove my JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension. The recent update of the extension is creating issues with colourization or syntax highlight. Thanks for hint.